# refresh adapter with recyclerview using D-pad holding focus

Tags: android-tv

I am stuck on a complex situation, when I am refreshing my adapter of recyclerview by notifyDataSetChanged, while it having focus on particular cell (with D-PAD), is being loss. After refresh focus is not showing

```
private void refreshedData() {
    flag1 = true;
    // new MyAsycTas().execute();
    focusedElement();

    // select();
    runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e(TAG, "Data refreshed starrt.......");
            // isRefreshedData = true;
            fetchXmlFromUrl = new FetchDataFromUrl(Demo2Activity.this, 0, Demo2Activity.this);
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            select();
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 9000);
        }
    };

    // handler.postDelayed(runnable,
    // Integer.valueOf(MyStaticClass.refreshTime) * 60000);
     handler.postDelayed(runnable, 9000);
}
```

...

```
public void select() {
    if (verticalListView != null) {
        View view = verticalListView.getChildAt(vertical_position);
        if (view != null) {
            view = verticalListView.getChildAt(vertical_position);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_recyclerview);
            if (recyclerView != null) {
                verticalListView.scrollToPosition(vertical_position);
                ((View) recyclerView.getChildAt(horizontal_position)).findViewById(R.id.cat_button_thumabnail)
                        .requestFocus();
            } else {
                LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.home_fragment_menu_container);
                linearLayout.getChildAt(horizontal_position).requestFocus();
            }
        }

    }
    // refreshedData();
}
```

..

```
public void focusedElement() {
    if (verticalListView != null) {
        View view = verticalListView.getLayoutManager().getFocusedChild();
        if (view != null) {
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_recyclerview);
            if (recyclerView != null) {
                vertical_position = (Integer) recyclerView.getTag();
                horizontal_position = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(recyclerView.getFocusedChild());
            } else {
                LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.home_fragment_menu_container);
                horizontal_position = ll.indexOfChild(ll.getFocusedChild());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess that the adapter is no way of knowing if the focused cell in the refreshed data set is actually the same. So it resets focus to the first cell. Answer yourself, what should happen if the focused item in recycleview would not be present in the new data set?

Comment: Actually I am saving position of that cell vertically & horizontally manually I am requesting for focus on that same points after notifydatasetchange but still I am not getting focus on the same position.

Comment: Could you also add code that saves the focus position and restores the focus?